# glib: Processing custom GMainContext* loop on another thread, not raising signal handlers

Tags: c++, glib, event-loop, networkmanager

I am trying to create a custom `GMainContext*` (so not to conflict with Qt/etc) and process the loop on a custom thread.

I am using `libnm` (for NetworkManager), but I don't think it is relevant.

The signal handlers aren't raised/processed when using a custom `GMainContext*`.

```cpp
#include <NetworkManager.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// Uncomment this for it to not work.
#define WORKING

static void test_callback ()
{
    std::cerr << "test callback";
}

static int thread(GMainContext *mainContext)
{
    GMainLoop* mainLoop = g_main_loop_new(mainContext, FALSE);
    g_main_loop_run(mainLoop);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef WORKING
    GMainContext* mainContext = g_main_context_default();
#else
    GMainContext* mainContext = g_main_context_new();
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(mainContext);
#endif

    GError* error = nullptr;
    NMClient* client = nm_client_new(nullptr, &error);

    g_signal_connect(client, NM_CLIENT_ACTIVE_CONNECTION_ADDED, G_CALLBACK(test_callback), nullptr);
    g_signal_connect(client, NM_CLIENT_ACTIVE_CONNECTION_REMOVED, G_CALLBACK(test_callback), nullptr);

    std::thread thread_obj(thread, mainContext);
    thread_obj.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The signal handlers are properly raised with `WORKING` defined, using `g_main_context_default()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because at least some of the underlying libnm `GSource`s are still being added to the global default `GMainContext` (the one always returned by `g_main_context_default()`). If you’re going to run a custom `GMainContext` in another thread, you need to ensure that all `GSource`s are attached to it; or you need to also run the global default `GMainContext` in the main thread.

If you are trying to run the `GMainContext` in one thread and a Qt main loop in the main thread, you are going to have to do a lot of thinking about the thread safety of data which is touched by both of them. It may be easier in the long run to chain the global default `GMainContext` to the Qt main loop (or vice versa) so that you only have one event loop running (in one thread). Then you don’t have to think about thread safety.

Comment: I am aware of the threading concerns. I am developing a C# wrapper for libnm and I want to hide the threading concerns from the implementations and internally dispatch operations onto a single internal thread.

If I use ```g_main_context_push_thread_default``` and process iterations for ```g_main_context_default```, it also doesn't work. This tells me that maybe libnm is internally inconsistent with the ```GMainContext*``` is uses. Maybe a bug in libnm?

Comment: Your best bet for debugging is to find all the `GMainContext` instances in the process’ address space (break on `g_main_context_new()` in `gdb`) and check what `GSource`s are attached to each of them. I am guessing you will find some `GSource`s attached to a `GMainContext` which is not being iterated.

Comment: As Philip says. Until recently, NMClient did not correctly handle multiple GMainContexts and was not working. This got fixed with 1.22.0 release. See commit https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/ce0e898fb476df740a1c337ac9910f504251c466